# Load balancing for text processing application

Tags: web-services, load, nlp

I have a resource-intensive NLP application that I want to put on the web, and I want to make it accessible concurrently by 100+ users.

I have an access to a cluster of a few machines. My idea is to run several background processes on these machines, then use a load balancing program to distribute the input from multiple clients. I wonder if I am on the right track and would welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several integration and scaling scenarios. Assuming that most of your components are NLP-related, I would recommend a framework tailored for NLP: the [Apache UIMA project](http://uima.apache.org/).
Useful for your scenario might be the [Apache UIMA Asynchronous Scaleout](http://uima.apache.org/doc-uimaas-what.html).